# How do a load a python package resource from the current distribution using pkg_resources?

Tags: python, pkg-resources

I have a Python package with some css stylesheets which I have included as resources like so:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    package_data={
        'my.package.name': ['*.css']
    }
    # ...
)
```

I would now like to load one of these included resources as a string. What is the best way to load a resource from the current package?

I see that the [`pkg_resources.Distribution`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#distribution-methods) object has a `get_resource_string()` method, but I am stuck on how to use this: How do I get a `Distribution` object for the current package?

Comment: If you scroll up a couple of lines from your own link, there is a section called '_Getting or Creating Distributions_'.

Answer (score 9):

There is a convenience method at the top level of `pkg_resources` for this:

```
import pkg_resources
my_data = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "my_style.css")
```

Comment: How do you reference files if they appear in, etc., `my.package.name.resources` directory?